# tiles not loading template

Tags: java, spring, tiles

Merry Christmas,

What's wrong please?

Not sure what may be happening already tested it all, do not know if I'm loading files in 
the wrong way, but all the examples I have followed the net are similar to what I created.

spring.xml

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer"
id="tilesConfigurer">
   <property name="preparerFactoryClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.SpringBeanPreparerFactory" />
   <property name="definitions">
   <list>
      <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
   </list>
   </property>
</bean>
```

tiles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.1//EN"
    "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_1.dtd">

<definition name="baseLayout" template="/public/template/template.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="Welcome" />
    <put-attribute name="header" value="/public/template/header.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="" />
    <put-attribute name="footer" value="/public/template/footer.jsp" />
</definition>

<definition name="index" extends="baseLayout">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/view/index.jsp" />
</definition>

<definition name="admin/home" extends="baseLayout">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/view/admin/home.jsp" />
</definition>
```

template.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title><tiles:insertAttribute name="title" ignore="true" /></title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="header">
    <tiles:insertAttribute name="header" />
</div>
    <tiles:insertAttribute name="body" />
    <tiles:insertAttribute name="footer" />
</body>
</html>
```

header.jsp

```
<h1>Header</h1>
```

Nothing happens, just shows the normal page without template.

Please, help me.

Comment: Could you please post your code from Spring's Controller?